# Kotlin. How to fix: None of following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am studying kotlin and have encountered this problem: `Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch.`

```
fun main(){
    val arg1 = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    val arg2 = listOf(2,3,4,5,6,7)

    sumLists(arg1, arg2)
}

fun <T: Number> sumLists(list1: List<T>, list2: List<T>): List<T>?{
    val res = mutableListOf<T>()
    if (list1.size != list2.size)
        return null
    else {
        for (i in 0..list1.size)
            res.add(list1[i] + list2[i])
    }
    return listOf()
}
```

I don't really understand why it doesn't work because I wrote `<T: Number>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Number + Number` operator defined in Kotlin, so the compiler can't guarantee that `T + T` is possible. For example, you can create your own class `MyNumber` which extends `Number`, but doesn't support add operation.

I believe there is no other way than write a separate code for each subtype of `Number` that you want to support:

```kotlin
for (i in 0 .. list1.lastIndex) {
    val item1 = list1[i]
    val item2 = list2[i]
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    val result = when {
        item1 is Int && item2 is Int -> item1 + item2
        item1 is Float && item2 is Float -> item1 + item2
        ...
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    } as T
    res.add(result)
}
```

We have to do unchecked cast here, because the compiler is not smart enough to understand that the type of the result is `T`.

Also, I changed for-loop bounds to `list1.lastIndex` to fix the off-by-one bug.

Comment: To illustrate one possible reason _why_ neither Java nor Kotlin provide a `Number.plus(Number)` function, consider what the result type should be… (The type would have to depend on _both_ of the input types, which doesn't fit into the object model and would need a lot of hard-coding — but that alone isn't enough. For example, adding two `Int`s could overflow an `Int` and need a `Long`. (contd)…

Comment: …And if you want to add a `Long` to a `Double`, then making the result a `Long` could result in overflow, while making it a `Double` could result in loss of precision. And what if you wanted to add a `Double` to a `BigDecimal`, or an `Int` to a custom `Number` subclass that I just wrote?)